# Fast way to get current user in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-identity

What is the fast way (best way) to get current user in ASP.NET Identity?

I wrote this code for getting current user but I don't know that is the best way or not?

```
public class MVCController : Controller
{
    public User CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            User currentUser = DataContextFactory.GetDataContext().Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.ToString() == currentUserId);
            return currentUser;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @DavidG : Version 2 or higher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Identity v2 the best way to get a user is to use the `UserManager` object.

```
var user = userManager.FindById(user.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Comment: Can you explain why this way is the best way?

Comment: Some useful info here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/12/per-request-lifetime-management-for-usermanager-class-in-asp-net-identity.aspx

Comment: And here http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a DB hit, we should add all required information in user claims during authentication and retrieve them from claims during next calls. It will be the fastest way to get commonly used user information and the same time we avoid any database calls.  You can take a look on some claims helper methods [Github link](https://github.com/rahulgarg1985/CodeNode.Identity/blob/master/CodeNode.Identity/Utilities/IdentityClaimsHelper.cs)